# ROS2 humble merge with QT framework

Tags: ros2, communication, qt, qtcreator

I have a project about robotics and I want to merge ros2 and Qt frameworks for UI and back-end systems for example, I want to use Qt for UI and some modules for inter-process communication because Qt is very high speed and ROS2 for outbox communication. How can I merge these two with together?

Answer (score 2):

Qt is already used regularly with ROS. The main visualization tools are Qt based.

[Rviz](https://index.ros.org/p/rviz2/) and [rqt](https://index.ros.org/p/rqt/) are the canonical examples I would recommend using as references for your design.

Comment: thanks for your replay, but I have to use qt for a node not application use it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar project where I needed to develop a GUI for my application. If you are okay with using PyQt5 and Qt Designer *(I am not a good at GUI programming, so I prefer the simplicity of Qt Designer)*, you can refer to [this](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/100861/using-qt-designer-and-ros2-together-for-a-gui) question to see how I implemented my GUI.

For a better example, you can check out [this](https://github.com/sampreets3/simple_gui) repo.

Comment: thank you for reply, but can I use qt framework for example signal and slot in ROS2 ?

Comment: you can use the event callbacks for each element, e.g., button clicked to send some data over a topic, or you can have a ROS node which subscribes to some topic, and on receiving data, you can update the text on a label. That functions like signals and slots, but not in the exact sense maybe.